# Sparkle: An error occurred while extracting the archive

Tags: macos, cocoa, sparkle

I am integrating sparkle into my app and testing it out. Currently, I am in a debug build ( I am running the app out of my Xamarin IDE). I also have an updated app in a http server. This updated .app is signed using an apple developer id, and it has been compressed into a .zip archive. I have provided the path to this .zip archive in the enclosure tag of my appcast.xml file.

Given this situation, when I run my app, I am expecting it to install the newer version of the app - but I am getting the following errors in my Application output window.

Sparkle: The update archive removes the DSA key, and the old app hasn't been signed with app Code Signing. At least one method of signature verification must be valid. The update will be rejected.
Sparkle: Error: An error occurred while extracting the archive. Please try again later. The update is improperly signed. (URL (null))

Could you please let me know how I could test out the sparkle "Install and relaunch" scenario?

Thanks,
Prashanth

Comment: You're using Sparkle in an iPhone app?

Comment: @mipadi no, on a mac.